# UBUNTU12.4(quantal) powerpc logon

Tags: boot

I work with a thrift store and we have an APPLE g3 ibook(dual USB) donated with some version of ubuntu. I downloaded the 12.4 version and the system asks for a password and username in the first screen.
I am not a linux/ubuntu expert. Need some help in 
either
a. Change the Username/login
or better
b. Remove the pw requirement.
This will allow us to sell the machine, which has an airline card etc in it.

cheers
vichu
PS: to save bandwidth, please feel free to send me an email dierctly.

Comment: 12.04 is Precise not Quantal(12.10)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just going to sell the computer it is best to do a fresh install so that all the old files are at least overwritten.

I would recommend that you install 12.04 not 12.10 as 12.10 is still in testing.  I would not be happy if I bought a computer that had an unstable OS

To install just boot into the Live USB or Live CD and select `Install Ubuntu`

When next screen comes up select `Replace Ubuntu version X with Ubuntu 12.04`
Mark the check box that says `format the drive` to reformat the drive and wipe all the documents and preferences

Then just let the installer run and when finished you should have a brand new Ubuntu installed.

BTW in doing this you will not need the old password.  To effectiely run Linux you need to have some password to do admin tasks.  Just choose some easy to remember password to install the system and tell the buyer to be sure to change it.  If you select using no password you can do **nothing** but boot the computer and run most programs, you cannot install remove or update without a password.  I.E. you have a limited account that is only slightly more useful than a guest acct.